# Scheme: Data serializing, efficient [and functional]

Tags: performance, serialization, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I'm serializing data which may be an integer, an object (list) with other nested objects, and trying to make a choice as to what approach to be using. Of two, the first one is to create bytevectors recursively and copy them in the calling functions to a larger single bytevector; the second one is to use some kind of the stream I could write to. Eventually, notwithstanding the choice, I would be able to use the resulting binary array in any further processing which may happen to occur, e. g. I would compress the output data and send it via network or just write some parts of it to a file.

I'd like to stay functional enough (or completely) yet implementing the fast serializer. I'm using [Racket](http://www.racket-lang.org/), though any other Scheme implementation will also do.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

Following are the examples I've added after I found a solution so that users save some time searching the way as to how to write data :]

`write-byte` and `write-bytes` are of particular use when you need to write octets.

```
> (bytes? (with-output-to-bytes (lambda () (write-byte 42))))
#t
> (bytevector? (with-output-to-bytes (lambda () (write-byte 42))))
#t
> (bytevector->u8-list (with-output-to-bytes (lambda () (write-byte 42))))
{42}
> (bytes->list (with-output-to-bytes (lambda () (write-byte 42) (write-bytes (integer->integer-bytes #x101CA75 4 #f #t)))))
(42 1 1 202 117)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use just `write` to write the data to a port.  You can do that with all values, as a list that holds everything.  It might need minor tweaking in case you have issues like cyclic data, where setting `print-graph` to `#t` will deal with it fine.  And if you want the output to go to a byte string, then you can use `open-output-bytes`, or the convenient `with-output-to-bytes` function:

```
(with-output-to-bytes (lambda () (write (list value1 value2 value3))))
```

This is not going to be as compact as a binary representation -- but if you plan on compressing the output anyway, it doesn't matter much.

Comment: `with-output-to-bytes` and friends usually create an output port and call some proc [with that port as its one argument]. However — in case I'd use your approach — I'd like to be able to pass any other arguments to my custom proc as it's done in my current implementation http://paste.lisp.org/display/113007 (proc `write-any`).

Comment: No, `with-output-to-bytes` expects a *thunk* -- a function of no arguments.  As for arguments, Scheme has lexical scope, and this function can use whatever names are bound.

Comment: I guess my function will no longer be a combinator if I go this way, since it would depend on variables unbound in its body, but which are bound outside of the latter.

Comment: (a) What's wrong with that?  (b) Note that you can do *very* little if you use strict combinators -- even `+` is something that you get from the lexical environment.  (And in Scheme, `lambda` is the same.)

Answer (score 2):

Probably `open-bytevector-output-port` is what I'm looking for:

```
#lang scheme

(require rnrs/bytevectors-6)
(require rnrs/io/ports-6)

(define-values (oup ext-proc) (open-bytevector-output-port))
(write 4 oup)
(write 2 oup)
(ext-proc)
(make-bytevector 3 1)
```

Result:

```
Добро пожаловать в DrScheme, версия 4.2.5 [3m].
Язык: scheme; memory limit: 128 MB.
#"42"
#"\1\1\1"
>
```